# XSL Transform, select namespace

Tags: xslt, namespaces, transform

I'm new with XSL, but it's ok, but it's the first time I need to do something with namespace, and I'm totally out, can someone explain how to do this :
I have an XHTML like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="5C.xslt"?> 
<!DOCTYPE rdf:RDF SYSTEM "http://purl.org/dc/schemas/dcmes-xml20000714.
dtd">

<rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
xmlns:dcterms="http://purl.org/dc/terms/">


<rdf:Description rdf:about="MyJPeg.jpg">
<dc:title>Find Info</dc:title>
<dc:contributor>Myself</dc:contributor>
<dcterms:created>2013-12-11</dcterms:created> 
<dcterms:issued>2013-12-23</dcterms:issued>
</rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>
```

I need to validate if the issued date if = to 2013-10-10 (answer no)

My XSLT is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<xsl:output method="html" version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="*">
<html><body><pre>
<xsl:value-of select="rdf/issued"/>
<xsl:if test="xxx = '2013-10-10' ">
</xsl:if>

</pre></body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

So I try to have ther value with this line :

```
<xsl:value-of select="rdf/issued"/>
```

(to see if I got it)
And to validate with this one :

```
<xsl:if test="xxx = '2013-10-10' ">
```

But I'm new with name space and I can't find out how to get my value, 
Can someone help me ?

thanks

Question #2, the solution works, but :
 If I want to validate if the date is HIGHER than instead of equal, how I can do that ? (I replace =  by >), and I change my date to be higher and lower, and each time it doesn't work

```
<xsl:if test="rdf:Description/dcterms:issued &gt; '2001-01-01' ">
Good job
</xsl:if>
```

What's wrong ?

thanks

Comment: Question #2, the solution works, but :
 If I want to validate if the date is HIGHER than instead of equal, how I can do that ? (I replace =  by &gt;), and I change my date to be higher and lower, and each time it doesn't work 

    <xsl:if test="rdf:Description/dcterms:issued &gt; '2001-01-01' ">
    Good job
    </xsl:if>

What's wrong ?

Comment: If the data you're processing is RDF then it would be much safer to process it using an RDF library rather than XML tools - there are many syntactically different but semantically equivalent ways to represent the same RDF graph in XML, and you may find your transformation stops working if you round-trip the RDF through a tool that uses a different representation from the one you expected.

Comment: thanks Ian. But finally I found something saying that I can't validate date. So I try this :<xsl:if test="number(substring(rdf:Description/dcterms:issued,1,4)) &gt;= 2002 and number(substring(rdf:Description/dcterms:issued,6,2)) &gt;= 1 and number(substring(rdf:Description/dcterms:issued,9,2)) &gt;= 10">
And I can validate now my date

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In XML, an element with a namespace if different to an element with no namespace. For example, despite having the same "local" name of "RDF" the following two elements are different.

```
<RDF>Test</RDF>
<rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">Test</RDF>
```

To access elements within a namespace in XSLT, you first have to declare the relevant namespaces in your XSTL

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
xmlns:dcterms="http://purl.org/dc/terms/">
```

Then, where you have an xpath expression that refers to elements, you need to add in the prefix

```
<xsl:value-of select="rdf:Description/dcterms:issued"/>
```

(I took it as a typo in your question, but "issued" is a child of "Description" in your XML sample!).

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
xmlns:dcterms="http://purl.org/dc/terms/">
<xsl:output method="html" version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="rdf:RDF">
<html><body><pre>
<xsl:value-of select="rdf:Description/dcterms:issued"/>
<xsl:if test="rdf:Description/dcterms:issued = '2013-10-10' ">
</xsl:if>

</pre></body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It is worth mentioning that the namespace prefix ("rdf:" in this case), does not have to be the same in the XML as it is in the XSLT. It is the namespace URI ("http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#") that has to match.

Comment: Thanks @Tim , I try your code and it works. I will now take some minutes to cleary understanding this code. THANKS A LOT !!